# Use rowspan attribute in <style> tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to use rowspan(html's attribute) in `<style>`, like:

```
   <style>
     table td{
       rowspan: 2;
     }
    </style>
```

Is there anyway to do that, or anything to solve that ?
Thank for any suggestions !

Comment: Row span is not something that we can do in css. It is a particular attribute for table. There are some other things also like cellspacing, cellpadding,Colspan which we cannot do in css.

Comment: @Rohith I understood, i can not change rowspan via css :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`rowspan` is an an attribute on the `td` tag, it is not a CSS property.  See the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6

You will not be able to set the `rowspan` attribute via CSS, this would be similar to attempting to set the `href` of an `a` tag via CSS.

Comment: Yes, so i would like to set rowspan in css :)

Comment: @RongNK To the best of my knowledge this is not possible with plain CSS.

Comment: thank ! In my project, if i can do that, code will be clear and easy. Now, i must change is javascript :)

Comment: @RongNK Even if this were possible through some CSS manipulation framework, I would argue the clearest place to put it would be in the HTML as an attribute, where developers would expect to find it.

Comment: I am using JSF, so i can not set directly html's attribute, i can change component's attributes and css, but i can not change html'attribute :)

Comment: **You will not be able to set the rowspan attribute via CSS, this would be similar to attempting to set the href of an a tag via CSS.** Really need to highlight this point. Gives clarity to the answer.